# IDE support for Spring framework; Are they worth using?

Tags: java, spring, ide

I'm using Intellij IDEA Community Edition for IDE, and I like it a lot. However, it does not have any special "Spring support" (plug-ins/tools).

My next project uses Spring (which I'm not very familiar with), and I'm wondering whether I should consider changing my IDE from early on; e.g. to SpringSource eclipse/Intellij IDEA Professional.

Do you guys have any experience with these IDE-built-in Spring support? Is it worth using?

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion. I use the community version of Intellij IDEA. I'm right now downloading the Ultimate version :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you're using the Community edition of IntelliJ, which doesn't support Spring, but the commercial version does, and its support is absolutely stellar.

You can also use SpringSource Tool Suite, or Eclipse with the STS plugins installed, which has very good Spring support as well.

Comment: +1 for IntelliJ Ultimate Edition.  You can't beat it.  If you're doing Spring development, IDE support would definitely be worth the money.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you guys have any experience with these IDE-built-in Spring support? Is it worth using?

If you're using XML configuration, then using a plugin to get "static typing" and make XML resistant to breakages/refactorings is IMO a mandatory feature (Spring support means more but this is one of the most important features for me).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to go with Eclipse and Netbeans as both of them has good support for Spring.

Answer (score 1):

This is mis-information, Intellij IDEA has the best most robust intuitive [support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/java_ide.html) for Spring there is Spring is almost un-usuable on a medium to large project without the support that IDEA brings to the table.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using Intellij IDEA for IDE, and I
>   like it a lot. However, it does not
>   have any special "Spring support"
>   (plug-ins/tools).

This is simply wrong.  IntelliJ has terrific Spring support, the best there is.  You have to buy a license, but it's worth the money.